# Can I play .avi files on my xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360

I have an Xbox 360 and a MacBook Pro, both connected to the same wireless network. That's as far as I've ever gotten.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, provided the videos are encoded in [a format that the Xbox360 supports](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/xboxteam/december-2007-video-playback-faq). Also, you'll need to install some software on your MacBook to serve the video. Connect360 and [Rivet](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111221105/http://thelittleappfactory.com/rivet/) are commercial products do this. There's also [a question over on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1266/is-there-good-free-media-server-for-os-x-to-stream-movies-to-an-xbox-360) with some other options.